# C# Trouble Using Safe Thead or Background Worker

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Fairly frustrating since this seems to be well documented and the fact that I accomplished this before, but can't duplicate the same success.  Sorry, I'll try to relate it all clearly.

Visual Studio, C# Form, One Main Form has text fields, among other widgets.

At one point we have the concept that we are "running" and therefore gathering data.

For the moment, I started a one second timer so that I can update simulated data into some fields.  Eventually that one second timer will take the more rapid data and update it only once per second to the screen, that's the request for the application right now we update at the rate we receive which is a little over 70 Hz, they don't want it that way.  In addition some other statistics will be computed and those should be the field updates.  Therefore being simple I'm trying to just generate random data and update those fields at the 1 Hz rate.  And then expand from that point.

Definition and management of the timer: (this is all within the same class MainScreen)

```
System.Timers.Timer oneSecondTimer;
public UInt32 run_time = 0;
public int motion = 5;

private void InitializeTimers()
{
    this.oneSecondTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    this.oneSecondTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(oneSecondTimer_elapsed);
}

public void start_one_second_timer()
{
    run_time = 0;
    oneSecondTimer.Enabled = true;
}

public void stop_one_second_timer()
{
    oneSecondTimer.Enabled = false;
    run_time = 0;
}

Random mot = new Random();

private void oneSecondTimer_elapsed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    run_time++;
    motion = mot.Next(1, 10);

    this.oneSecondThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.UpdateTextFields));

    this.oneSecondThread.Start();
}

private void UpdateTextFields()
{
    this.motionDisplay.Text = this.motion.ToString();
}
```

motionDisplay is just a textbox in my main form.  I get the Invalid Operation Exception pointing me towards the help on how to make Thread-Safe calls.  I also tried backgroundworker and end up with the same result.  The details are that motionDisplay is accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

So looking for some suggestions as to where my mistakes are.

Best Regards.  I continue to iterate on this and will update if I find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the multiple answers.  I'm not disagreeing with any of them.  Chose the simplest because of simplicity.  Now as I progress and cache some faster (70 Hz) data for a chart and then only update it at my 1 second timeout, maybe then I'll find that a different method may be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `System.Forms.Timer` rather than a `System.Timers.Timer`.  It will fire it's elapsed event in the UI thread.

Don't create a new thread to update the UI; just do the update in the elapsed event handler.

Comment: I have to admit that I did this because ... it's simple.  There are so many ways to skin the cat.  Their documentation says that the preferred method is to use background workers.  Pretty bad that there are like half a dozen very different ways to do this.

Comment: @user2311569 If you had CPU bound work that needed to be done in a background thread, and you wanted to update the UI with the progress and then results of that CPU bound work, then a `BackgroundWorker` is exactly the right tool.  To execute a UI operation after a set period of time, or periodically after every given interval of time, then you use a `Timer`.

Comment: By the way, I found it to be System.Windows.Forms.Timer and that did work.

Comment: just to make sure you and I aren't interpreting CPU bound differently.  To me that means that I'd be out of CPU resources and/or memory (RAM) where I'd have to break up functions or calculations.  Right now there are no indications that there are any situations like that.  It's keeping up and actually I think that if instead of plotting multiple series (16) at about 70 Hz to a fastline chart, I'd instead plot 70 added samples once per second and that will probably free up time even though I wasn't at any limit as yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void UpdateTextFields()
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler((s,e)=>{
        this.motionDisplay.Text = this.motion.ToString();
    }));
}
```

This will properly marshall a call back to the main thread.

The thing with WinForm development is that all the controls are not thread safe. Even getting a property such as .Text from another thread can cause these type of errors to happen. To make it even more frustrating is that sometimes it will work at runtime and you won't get an exception, other times you will.

Comment: Yep, that's what the documentation says too about "sometimes" exception, and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
private delegate void UpdateMotionDisplayCallback(string text);
private void UpdateMotionDisplay(string text) {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.motionDisplay.InvokeRequired) {
            UpdateMotionDisplayCallback d = new UpdateMotionDisplayCallback(UpdateMotionDisplay);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        } else {
            this.motionDisplay.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

When you want to update the text in motionDisplay just call:

```
UpdateMotionDisplay(this.motion.ToString())
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion as well, a potential first next try for when I take higher rate data (70 Hz) and add it to the form's chart at one second intervals.  I'll have to see first if the simple form chosen of System.Windows.Forms.Timer runs into trouble when I give it more work to accomplish.

Comment: @user2311569 The forms timer is pretty much just a regular timer that's calling this method on your behalf before firing the event so you don't have to.